# Changing Values of elements in Pandas Datastructure

Tags: python, pandas, data-structures

I have imported .xls file
with

```
ene2 = pd.read_excel('Energy Indicators.xls', index=False)
```

head looks like this

```
print(ene2.head())          
          Country Energy Supply Energy Supply per Capita % Renewable's
15             NaN    Petajoules               Gigajoules             %
16     Afghanistan           321                       10       78.6693
17         Albania           102                       35           100
18         Algeria          1959                       51       0.55101
19  American Samoa           ...                      ...      0.641026
```

lets say that i used FOR loop to exchange some values

```
for value in ene2['Energy Supply']:
    if value == 'Petajoules':
        value = 'Gigajoules'
        print(value)
```

inside the loop things looks good

however printing head again,

```
print(ene2.head())
```

show me that, no change has been applied to the DataStructure iteslf

and tail looks exactly as above, but i expected it go got change.

### **QUESTION**

### What should i do else, to make the change valid and implemented inside Datastructure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of:

```
value = 'Gigajoules'
```

do this:

```
ene2.loc[ene2['Energy Supply'] == value, 'Energy Supply'] = 'Gigajoules'
```

You have to set it to the relevant cell, by filtering for the correct rows and columns with `.loc`. The other answer is the simpler method, but I wanted you to understand that you are not making the changes back to the dataframe with just value = blah.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use [`Series.replace`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.replace.html):

```
ene2['Energy Supply'] = ene2['Energy Supply'].replace('Petajoules', 'Gigajoules')
```