# Data Frame - changing of the nested variable

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

We are discussing data that is imported from excel

```
ene2 = pd.read_excel('Energy Indicators.xls', index=False)
```

recently I asked in post, where answers were clear, straightforward and brought success.

[Changing Values of elements in Pandas Datastructure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62065985/changing-values-of-elements-in-pandas-datastructure)

However I went steps further, and I have similar (sic!) problem, where assigning variable does not change anything.

Lets consider Data Structure

```
print(ene2.head())
```

```
               Country Energy Supply Energy Supply per Capita % Renewable's
    15             NaN    Gigajoules               Gigajoules             %
    16     Afghanistan     321000000                       10       78.6693
    17         Albania     102000000                       35           100
    18        Algeria1    1959000000                       51       0.55101
    19  American Samoa           ...                      ...      0.641026

238                            Viet Nam    2554000000                       28       45.3215
239           Wallis and Futuna Islands             0                       26             0
240                               Yemen     344000000                       13             0
241                              Zambia     400000000                       26       99.7147
242                            Zimbabwe     480000000                       32       52.5361
243                                 NaN           NaN                      NaN           NaN
244                                 NaN           NaN                      NaN           NaN
```

where some countries have index (like Algieria1 or Australia12)
I want to change those names to become just Algieria, Australia and so on.

There is in total 20 entries that suppose to be changed.
I developed a method to do it, which at the last step fails..

```
for value in ene2['Country']:
    if type(value) == float: # to cover NaN values
        continue

    x = re.findall("\D+\d", value) # to find those countries/elements which are with number

    while len(x) > 0: # this shows elements with number, otherwise answer is [], which is 0
        for letters in x: # to touch letters
            right = letters[:-1] # and get rid of the last number
            ene2.loc[ene2['Country'] == value, 'Country'] = right # THIS IS ELEMENT WHICH FAILS <= it does not chagne the value
        x = re.findall("\D+\d", value) # to bring the new value to the while loop
```

Code above should make the task, to finally remove all the indexes from the names,
however the code - ene2.loc[...] which used to work previously, here, where is nested, just do nothing.

What could be the case that this exchange does not work, how can I overcome the problem a) in a old style way b) in the Panda way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code suggest you already use pandas, so why not use the built-in replace method with regex?

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data=["Afghanistan","Albania", "Algeria1", "Algeria9999"], columns=["Country"])
df["Country_clean"] = df["Country"].str.replace(r'\d+$', '')
```

output:

```
print(df["Country_clean"])

0    Afghanistan
1        Albania
2        Algeria
3        Algeria
Name: Country, dtype: object
```